# How to redirect from one URL to another

Tags: redirect, 301-redirect

I had a site running with url "`http://domain-a.com`". Now the server running that site is decommisioned and all the contents are moved to another site with url "`http://domain-b.com`".

What I want is, in case anyone try to use the old site url (with a bookmark or some printed text) then I want them to get redirected to the new site, with new site's URL appearing in their browser address bar.

The developer told me that he maintained a HTML page with `META http-equiv="refresh" content="...."` tag to perform a HTML redirection.

But now the server running the site is powered down but I still want the same redirect experience for the user, at least for few more months. Is here any way I can achieve this without a target server where the old url points to?

I assume there is no way I can achieve this using CNAME record as I really want he new URL to be seen on the user's browser bar.

Thank you

Arun

Comment: You configure your web server to send the redirect.

Comment: Thanks Michael. But the problem is the web server running old site is now powered down. It s not available now. When it was there the html page based script used to do redirect

Comment: Why don't you just create the redirect on the new server?

Comment: Hi Reaces, apologize for not making it clear. In my case the old server is gone and anyone try to access the old site need to be redirected  to the new server

Comment: @Arun You're being very clear. However the same method used to transfer your other web pages to the new server can be used to transfer the old HTML page to the new server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to alter the DNS record for *domain-a.com* so it points to *domain-b.com* IP address, and on a web-server that is serving the *domain-b.com* site you need to do the same thing with redirection. One more thing: HTML redirect is some sort of old legacy way, the modern approach is either to set up an alias for the *domain-a.com* on a *domain-b.com* virtualhost (so virtualhost will serve both), or, if the *domain-b.com* is obsoleted, to set up an explicit 301 redirect using your web-server configuration directives.